# Generate Complex Json in scala

Tags: scala

How can I generate the following JSON format with scala?

sample json format:

```
[
   [
      {
         "clmn_nm":"City",
         "clmn_val_txt":"NYC"
      },
      {
         "clmn_nm":"State",
         "clmn_val_txt":"New York"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "clmn_nm":"City",
         "clmn_val_txt":"Philadelphia"
      },
      {
         "clmn_nm":"State",
         "clmn_val_txt":"Pennsylvania"
      }
   ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is basically a `List(List[(String,String)]))`. Then most of scala's json libraries should have no issues serializing to the desired format. Example with circe:

```
  import io.circe.syntax._
  val v = List(List(("aaa", "bbb"))).asJson
```